# Change content in tailwind based on sidebar

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to build a dashboard in tailwind and I want  to add content  to it and change it when a button is pressed.
Here is my code

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
    <div class="md:flex flex-col md:flex-row md:min-h-screen w-full">
      <div @click.away="open = false" class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-64 text-gray-700 bg-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 dark-mode:bg-gray-800 flex-shrink-0" x-data="{ open: false }">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0 px-8 py-4 flex flex-row items-center justify-between">
          <a href="#" class="text-lg font-semibold tracking-widest text-gray-900 uppercase rounded-lg dark-mode:text-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Dashboard</a>
          <button class="rounded-lg md:hidden rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @click="open = !open">
            <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="w-6 h-6">
              <path x-show="!open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM9 15a1 1 0 011-1h6a1 1 0 110 2h-6a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
              <path x-show="open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
        <nav :class="{'block': open, 'hidden': !open}" class="flex-grow md:block px-4 pb-4 md:pb-0 md:overflow-y-auto">
          <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-gray-700 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Blog</a>
          <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Portfolio</a>
          <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Contact</a>
          <div @click.away="open = false" class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
            <button @click="open = !open" class="flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-left bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 md:block hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
              <span>Dropdown</span>
              <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" :class="{'rotate-180': open, 'rotate-0': !open}" class="inline w-4 h-4 mt-1 ml-1 transition-transform duration-200 transform md:-mt-1"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
            </button>
            <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95" class="absolute right-0 w-full mt-2 origin-top-right rounded-md shadow-lg">
              <div class="px-2 py-2 bg-white rounded-md shadow dark-mode:bg-gray-800">
                <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Link #1</a>
                <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Link #2</a>
                <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Link #3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is what I want to get :
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abesN.png)